# Show all errors after click submit

Tags: php, validation

How can I show all errors when a user clicks on submit. As example I have this piece of code:

```
if(strlen($username) < 5){ echo "Show error message"; }
if($password != $passwordRetype){ echo "Show error message"; }
if(strlen($password) < 8){ echo "Show error message"; }
```

How can I show all error message in a time? Now it shows, first error, if this is fixed the second one and after the second one the thirth. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The second `if` statement has too many closing parenthesis.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean exactly? Oeps, sorry already fixed.

Comment: You can do this best in javascript (or jQuery which is easier). Otherwise, if a field fails validation you must refresh the screen and (unless you store/replace user's typing) fields will be emptied. See my answer if this interests you.

Comment: @gibberish Data validation should **always** be done on the server. Always. Client-site validation is a nice-to-have, helping users to fill in the correct data, but it is not reliable (in fact, because of how the internet works it *cannot* be reliable).

Comment: And if it's an intranet, with non-critical data? IMO, there are a number of occasions when this strategy is both useful and appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list/array to keep track of all errors that occur, then present them back to the user like so, in this very simple demonstration.

```
$errors = []; // Array creation
if (strlen($username) < 5) { 
    // Add this error to our list
    $errors[] = 'Username not valid.';
} 

if ($password != $passwordRetype) {
    // Add this error to our list
    $errors[] = 'Password does not match our records.';
}

// Repeat this process for other errors
// Then handle your list of errors
foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo "Error Found: $error<br>";
}
```

Comment: Other comments have been made that you should really validate textual inputs in Javascript before ever posting. You should also look into that. I do both, I validate in JS and slip in some minor validation in my PHP as a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Do something as

```
$error = false ;
$msg = '';
if(strlen($username) < 5){ $msg .= "Show error message<br />"; $error = true ;}
if($password != $passwordRetype)){ $msg .= "Show error message<br />"; $error = true ;}
if(strlen($password) < 8){ $msg .="Show error message<br />"; $error = true ;}

if($error === true){
 echo $msg ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED to show `<form>` tags and using jQuery to submit form.

Really, you should be doing this field testing in javascript/jQuery rather than in PHP.  By the time it gets to the PHP side, if something fails validation and you need to go back, the screen will refresh and you either have to store/replace the values or else already-inputted field values will be lost.

With javascript/jQuery you can stop the validation prior to the redirection and preserve field values and save yourself a bit of work.

Here's a simple example:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4g4e/1/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myForm" action="some_file.php" method="post">
One: <input type="text" id="f1"><br />
Two: <input type="text" id="f2"><br />
Three: <input type="text" id="f3"><br />
Four: <input type="text" id="f4"><br />
</form>
<br />
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Go" />
```

**javascript/jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

var chkFld, arrAll = {'One':'f1','Two':'f2','Three':'f3','Four':'f4'};

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    var errMsg='', badFlds='', firstBad='';
    for(var key in arrAll){
        chkFld = arrAll[key];
        if ($('#'+chkFld).val() ==''){
            //alert('Please complete field ' + arrAll[key] );
            errMsg += '*' + chkFld + '\n';
            if (firstBad=='') firstBad=chkFld;
        }
    }
    if (errMsg != '') {
        alert(errMsg);
        $('#'+firstBad).focus();
        return false;
    }
    $('#myForm').submit();
}); //END mybutt.click

}); //END document.ready
</script>
```

Notes:

1. It is not necessary to use a button with type="submit". Using jQuery to submit the form works perfectly well.
2. If form fails validation, use `return false;` to stop processing at that point and return control to the user.
3. If form passes validation, use `$('#formID').submit();` to submit the form
4. Ensure your `action=` and `method=` attributes (form tag) are correct.

ALSO Note that the above example uses jQuery. Make sure to include the jQuery library in your document, usually between the head tags, thus:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks, but why do you create this: var chkFld, arrAll = {'One':'f1','Two':'f2','Three':'f3','Four':'f4'};? Is it mandatory to set the 'label' before the 'f1', 'f2', 'f3' and 'f4'? Why it is?

Comment: In javascript, that's an array/object. Each field is listed as a pair (field ID, field title in English) so that at the same time you get both the next field ID to check AND the name of that field to tell the user -- after all, you don't want to tell user that field `pcode` is empty, you want to tell him to fill-in the `Postal Code` field.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, what I always do for showing errors to users is basically this:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
 $_SESSION['errors'][] = 'Email was invalid';
}
if($address == '') {
 $_SESSION['errors'][] = 'Address was invalid';
}

if(isset($_SESSION['errors'])) {
 header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
 exit();
} else {
 //everything okay, do other stuff like send mail or save to database
}
```

Then, on the page itself, I use a list:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['errors'])) {
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $err) {
  echo '<li>' . $err . '</li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';
 unset($_SESSION['errors']); //show them just once
}
```

That way users will not be able to re-post data already submitted by hitting F5 and they will not get an ugly url like ?post=success.